# Charting sporadic events over time on Highcharts (Dynamic Precision?)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, charts, highcharts

How would you chart something like pageviews over time using Highcharts?

Given that page views take place at sporadic irregular intervals, how could you chart this as accurately and legibly as possible?

One way is to group pageviews into time intervals (like days), and then sum up all pageviews on any given day.

The obvious issue  here is that if you are only looking at data for a few days, the intervals are too large, and the data fits basically into a few buckets (not really showing any trends).

Another solution I thought of is to have a minimum interval (say, 7 steps) and when less than 7 days of data are requested, (say 3) I could divide that time period into 7 intervals.

However this seems like too much fuss, especially on the backend, for the purpose of simply showing data.

Given that the underlying data does not change, only the manner in which it's rendered, I figured there must be a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to discover in the data.  If you want to compare it with another data set then use the same scheme it does ("pageviews per day" or whatever).  If you want to spot trends over time you need to decide on your horizon and use an appropriate time period (so, for example, if you are trying to justify the purchase of a larger server then perhaps quarterly data comparing this year to last would be good).  Designing visualizations for datasets is a huge topic.

So, in other words, I think you pretty much answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is forced Data Grouping

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

```
forced: Boolean
```

> When data grouping is forced, it runs no matter how small the
>   intervals are. This can be handy for example when the sum should be
>   calculated for values appearing at random times within each hour.
>   Defaults to false.

I'll try this and see if it works well

---

This could work for highstock, but it's not part of highcharts...